# When creating objects, created_at stores microsecond precision that json can't match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I just noticed something which is causing me a tad bit of trouble.

I am creating an object. This object goes into the database with this:

```
created_at: "2015-11-12 08:37:35.413663"
```

I didn't realize it stores beyond `.413`

You can confirm this is saved and not simply for our viewing pleasure by doing the following: `object.created_at.nsec #=> 413663000`

When my front-end receives my JSON, the created_ at attribute becomes: `"2015-11-12T08:37:35.413Z"`, which I would expect. The problem here is that we lose valuable information because now we don't have the 633 microseconds.

Indeed, if you do `"2015-11-12T08:37:35.413Z".to_time.nsec #=> 413000000`.

What this means is when you do the following, you're going to get no item:

`Object.where(created_at: object.created_at.as_json).first #=> nil`

How does one mitigate this? How does one account for the microseconds, or rather, query for created_at, with only millisecond precision hope.

Comment: Upon further google-fu, this may be what I need: https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/d074d22a736d49459b15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I decided on changing the datetime columns in my DB.

I basically applied the following wherever relevant in a migration:

`change_column table, column, :datetime, limit: 3`

That successfully makes sure that my :datetime columns all only go to the milliseconds.

I think it is a good change because when the sole purpose of my back-end is to render a JSON API, then I think through and through it should be cohesive. JSON API standards are ISO 8601. As such, I'd like my DB to adhere to that.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.now.to_s` doesn't return the fractional seconds, as you need more precision, you can use `DateTime.now.iso8601(10)` at your created parameter.

```
m = ModelName.create(created_at: DateTime.now.iso8601(10))
```

or

```
m = ModelName.create()
m.created_at = DateTime.now.iso8601(10)
m.save
```

I have tried somewhat similar what have you described to test:

```
p=Product.create(created_at: DateTime.now.iso8601(10))
p.created_at.nsec
=> 61103188

 Product.where(created_at: p.created_at)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 172, manufacturer: nil, created_at: "2015-11-12 10:11:31", updated_at: "2015-11-12 10:11:31", avatar: nil>]>
```